# How can I "add" Depth information to the main frame buffer

Tags: opengl, glsl

Let's say I have this scene
[image]

And I want to add depth information from a custom made fragment shader.

Now the intuitive thing to do would be to draw a quad over my teapot without depth test enabled but with glDepthMask( 1 ) and glColorMask( 0, 0, 0, 0 ). Write some fragments gl_FragDepth and discard some other fragments.

```
if ( gl_FragCoord.x < 100 )
    gl_FragDepth = 0.1;
else
    discard;
```

For some reason, on a NVidia Quadro 600 and K5000 it works as expected but on a NVidia K3000M and a Firepro(dont't remember which one), all the area covered by my discarded fragments is given the depth value of the quad.

Can't I leave the discarded fragments depth values unmodified?

**EDIT** I have found a solution to my problem. It turns out that as Andon M. Coleman and Matt Fishman pointed out, I have early_fragment_test enabled but not because I enabled it, but because I use imageStore, imageLoad.

With the little time I had to address the problem, I simply copied the content of my current depth buffer just before the "add depth pass" to a texture. Assigned it to a uniform sampler2D. And this is the code in my shader:

```
if ( gl_FragCoord.x < 100 )
    gl_FragDepth = 0.1;
else
{
    gl_FragDepth = texture( depthTex, gl_PointCoord ).r;
    color = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    return;
}
```

This writes a completely transparent pixel with an unchanged z value.

Comment: What OpenGL versions are you using?

Comment: This issue _might_ be related to the early z test - in that case, the depth value written by the shader has no effect and even discarded fragments might be written to the depth buffer (which perfectly makes sense HW-wise, since the test and the Z buffer update are typically an atomic conditional memory update, not two separate steps). However, an implementation should behave as if early z test is only used when you enable it (it might under the hood use them also in "safe cases", where no discards and no depth writes occur in the frag shader.).

Comment: If you are speaking of "early_fragment_tests", it is not enabled. I have another program that needs this feature but not this particular one.

Comment: You are not using image load/store, are you? That implicitly enables early fragment testing.

Comment: Hmmmm, really. I enable early fragment testing in the pass that accumulates the fragments into a linked list. But in the pass that I write to the depth buffer, I only Load that linked list using the imageLoad method. I had no clue this would implicitly enable the early fragment testing.

Comment: You may be right, even if I only use imageStore in another program, I may have to enable early_fragment_tests : https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Memory_Model#Incoherent_memory_access

Comment: I may try a memoryBarrierImage​ when I have the time.

Comment: The memory barrier did not help. But I found another solution, check the EDIT I made in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it sounds like a driver bug to me -- discarded fragments should not hit the depth buffer.  You could bind the original depth buffer as a texture, sample it using the `gl_FragCoord`, and then write the result back instead of using `discard`.  That would add an extra texture lookup -- but it might be a suitable workaround.

**EDIT:** From section 6.4 of the [GLSL 4.40 Specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.40.pdf):

> The discard keyword is only allowed within fragment shaders. It can be
>   used within a fragment shader to  abandon the operation on the current
>   fragment. This keyword causes the fragment to be discarded and **no 
>   updates to any buffers will occur**. Control flow exits the shader, and
>   subsequent implicit or explicit 
>   derivatives are undefined when this exit is non-uniform. It would
>   typically be used within a conditional  statement, for example:
>
> `if (intensity < 0.0)  discard;`
>
> A fragment shader may test a fragment’s
>   alpha value and discard the fragment based on that test.  However, it
>   should be noted that coverage testing occurs after the fragment shader
>   runs, and the coverage  test can change the alpha value.if

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured I would need to do, thanks for the answer. I will write a simple program reproducing the problem to confirm it's a driver bug. I would really like to see where in the spec it is said that a discarded fragment should not write to the depth when depth mask is 1.

Comment: So we could deduce that even if depth mask is 1 and depth test is "always", the depth value should NOT be updated. It still seems strange that 2 different graphic card manufacturers would code the same bug in their drivers.

Comment: The problem occurred on K3000M Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 with the Firepro card. All with the latest available drivers at the moment. The answer is good enough, I will confirm it as a solution. Even if that's not what I wanted to read :)

Comment: Sorry about that :( I've had problems with shaders on some laptop CPUs too. I had an old ATI Radeon card that didn't handle framebuffer objects properly.

Comment: Not a driver problem after all. Check the EDIT I made to my post.

Answer (score 1):

Posting a separate answer, because I found some new info in the OpenGL spec:

> If early fragment tests are enabled, any depth value computed by the
>   fragment shader has no effect. Additionally, the depth buffer, stencil
>   buffer, and occlusion query sample counts may be updated even for
>   fragments or samples that would be discarded after fragment shader
>   execution due to per-fragment operations such as alpha-to-coverage or
>   alpha tests.

Do you have early fragment testing enabled?  More info: [Early Fragment Test](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Early_Fragment_Test)

Comment: No I don't have early fragment tests enabled, maybe I should write a simple example and post the whole code to clarify. At first I had it then I split my program in two passes.

Comment: Check the EDIT I made in my post.